# How will javascript bundling evolve for http/2?

Tags: webpack, http2, javascript-build

I've seen it casually mentioned in explanations of http/2 that techniques like bundling JS files will no longer be necessary and are anti-patterns for getting around limitations of http 1.1.

Thinking about it, it doesn't seem like the problem is much easier just because server push exists. Right now we have tools like webpack, which builds a dependency graph of the `require()`s or ES6 `import`s and then combines them into a single file. The nice thing is this results in a single static file which can be served from a CDN.

In http/2, you still need the initial step of building the graph so you know what to server-push to the client. If you do it dynamically on the server, you can't serve from a CDN. You could resolve the js graph at build time and put them all as script tags at the bottom of your index.html, and webservers could know to server-push those resources (though I think you'd need some kind of browser support to consolidate that with the `require`s in the code?). But if your html is not served by the cdn that won't work. And since you're passing down every file on any page load it seems like there's little benefit to this over a single bundle. I guess you could build a few of these for different key routes, but that's no different than building multiple bundles in webpack, and how do you transition to a different part of the app that might not be downloaded yet?

On top of this, it's very likely that you'll still have a static resource build step, for e.g. browser compatibility of the latest js features, for sass-type css compiling, for saving icons at both @1x and @2x resolution, etc. So, it seems there are a lot of other benefits to the current webpack-style approach of compiling a js bundle, and it's unclear how http/2 server-push could really help that.

What am I missing? Are there other benefits to serving js over http/2 server-push that I'm not thinking of? Does anyone have links to resources from experts or popular web frameworks on plans for serving js apps on http/2?

Comment: I'm not sure if your question is a good fit for this site, since it mostly asks for an open discussion. I have given my opinions to what you ask here: https://forum.shimmercat.com/t/javascript-bundling-http-2-and-cdns/29?u=alcidesv

Comment: Thanks for responding!